# Narrow return type in PHP7

Tags: php, type-hinting, php-7.1

Is it somehow possible to narrow return type in PHP7.1 type hints?

The following code causes fatal error `Declaration of A::foo(): Obj must be compatible with IA::foo(): IObj`, even through narrowing the return type does not break inheritance typing principles: Obj implements IObj, therefore parent class return type constraint will be always satisfied when Obj instance is returned.

```
interface IObj {}
class Obj implements IObj {}
interface IA {
    function foo(): IObj;
}

class A implements IA {
    function foo(): Obj {
        return new Obj();
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a PHP drawback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no guarantee that `Obj implements IObj` as far as PHP is concerned. Because you may at any time move the declaration of `Obj` into some other file, and since files are loaded at runtime and not in some compile step, it's entirely unknown what implementation of `Obj` will be loaded at runtime and whether that will `implements IObj`.

So, no, you cannot change the return type in an implementation since then all type safety goes out the window. Type safety could only be guaranteed if you pre-compiled the code which nails down what exactly `Obj` will be in advance.

Comment: I'm not aware of any compiled languages that let you change the return type in subclasses/implementations either.

Comment: As a spontaneous example TypeScript comes to mind, in which you can override pretty much anything as long as the types remain compatible; if I'm not completely off my rockers right now.

Comment: I admit, I was thinking more along the lines of C++, Java, or C#.

Comment: @Powerlord It compiles fine in Java. Of course you cannot change return type to anything completely different, but using a descendant is fine as it is not a change, just adding strictness to the return type.

Comment: PHP's dynamic nature makes *consistently* verifying covariant return types tricky and that's why it doesn't do it. Levi Morrison, who did the return types RFC, did want to support it.