# How to implement interface that uses another interface that uses the first one, and whose child classes use the concrete classes of those interfaces?

Tags: php, oop

For example, there are 2 interfaces:

```
interface IParser {
    function toObject(string $str): IEntity;
}

interface IEntity {
    static function getParser(): IParser; 
}
```

And each child class implements interface methods with concrete objects of that class:

```
class Entity implements IEntity {
    static function getParser(): Parser {
        return new Parser();
    }
}

class Parser implements IParser {
    function toObject(string $str): Entity {
        return new Entity();
    }
}
```

But I get an error that PHP does not see the `Parser` class when I need to check if it belongs to a specific interface.

P. S. I need each `IParser` child class to have a tostr method that works with a specific `Entity`. I think I know what it would look like in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T> class IParser {
public:
    virtual std::string parse(T* entity) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class IEntity {
public:
    static IParser<T>* getParser() {
        return new IParser<T>();
    }
};

struct CurrentEntity1;
struct CurrentEntity2;

class CurrentParser1 : public IParser<CurrentEntity1> {
public:
    virtual std::string parse(CurrentEntity1* entity);
};

class CurrentParser2 : public IParser<CurrentEntity2> {
public:
    virtual std::string parse(CurrentEntity2* entity);
};

struct CurrentEntity1 : IEntity<CurrentEntity1> {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    int date;

    CurrentEntity1(int id, std::string name, int date) : id(id), name(name), date(date) {   }

    static CurrentParser1* getParser() {
        return new CurrentParser1();
    }

};

struct CurrentEntity2 : IEntity<CurrentEntity2> {
    int id;
    std::string prop1;
    std::string prop2;

    CurrentEntity2(int id, std::string prop1, std::string prop2)
        : id(id + 1), prop1(prop1), prop2(prop2) {  }

    static CurrentParser2* getParser() {
        return new CurrentParser2();
    }

};


std::string CurrentParser1::parse(CurrentEntity1* entity)
{
    return std::to_string(entity->id) + " => date: " + std::to_string(entity->date) + "; name: " + entity->name;
}

std::string CurrentParser2::parse(CurrentEntity2* entity)
{
    return "[" + std::to_string(entity->id) + "]: " + entity->prop1 + "; " + entity->prop2;
}

int main() {
    auto ent1 = CurrentEntity1{ 2, "test", 2020};
    auto parser1 = CurrentEntity1::getParser();
    std::cout << parser1->parse(&ent1) << std::endl; // 2 => date: 2020; name: test

    auto ent2 = CurrentEntity2{ 2, "val1", "val2"};
    auto parser2 = CurrentEntity2::getParser();
    std::cout << parser2->parse(&ent2); // [3]: val1; val2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the interface. Your IParser no loner returns IEntity but Entity (e.g. no other IEntity will be allowed, you are narrowing the interface). Instead try:

```
class Entity implements IEntity {
    static function getParser(): IParser {
        return new Parser();
    }
}

class Parser implements IParser {
    function toObject(string $str): IEntity {
        return new Entity();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty, but I think this is a bit not what I wanted. I've updated the description to be more specific.

Comment: @NaN I'm afraid that's not possible in PHP, because it's a dynamic language (it's possible to define the Parser class in an if/else statements, so it can not guarantee whether it will be implementing IParser at the end or not). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47225204/797303